# Translation Strings in xml not working

Tags: android, string

i have this code for my spinner. and its include title and subtitle and image.

```
public class Gold extends Activity implements OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
String[] strings = {"Gold", "Sliver"};
String[] subs = {"Gold 24 India"};
int arr_images[] = { R.drawable.gold24};
```

...

```
        public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
        View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.SelectUnits);
        label.setText(strings[position]);
        TextView sub=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.sub);
        sub.setText(subs[position]);
        ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.image);
        icon.setImageResource(arr_images[position]);

        return row;
```

i added translation to strings.xml but it doesn't work.

**my question is how can i add translation to this method of strings?**

thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out i18n and L10n for android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you add your strings to strings.xml ?
You have to actually call this data from the strings.xml file, like so :

```
String[] strings = {getResources().getString(R.string.key_gold), getResources().getString(R.string.key_silver)}
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer ... i tried it but its givin me force close.

Comment: its givin me this: error opening trace file:No such file or directory (2)

Comment: Is your strings.xml in the values folder?

Comment: This may be unrelated but... How come your arrays don't have the same number of elements ? That is, if `position` is equal to 1, it will crash your application.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding Strings in the Java Code :

```
String[] strings = {"Gold", "Sliver"};
String[] subs = {"Gold 24 India"};
```

Add the array itself in String.xml file

like

```
<string-array name="strings">
        <item>Gold</item>
        <item>Silver</item>
    </string-array>
```

Similar way add translations for it , then translation will work

Read it like this:

```
    final String[] m_string= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.strings);

    List<String> m_list = Arrays.asList(m_string);
```

Comment: hello, thanks for your answer.i used this method but the sub titles and images not appear in the spinner.

Comment: yes because this is a half solution, you need to read the value in Spinner from your Strings file

Comment: its givin me this: error opening trace file:No such file or directory (2)